# change url of HttpClient in angular when the language is changed

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

im trying to make a portfolio where when if someone wants changes the language in the menu the components change what json load for getting all data. I try to use BehaviourSubject and subject but i cant understand them so it difficult to use them. sorry for any mistake in english im learning

this is my service

```
export class PortfolioService {
  language: string = 'espaniol';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  obtenerDatos(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.language === 'espaniol') {
      return this.http.get('./assets/i18n/espaniol.json');
    } else {
      return this.http.get('./assets/i18n/english.json');
    }
  }

  changeLang(value: string) {
    this.language = value;
  }
}
```

this is my header

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  @Input() currentSection = 'section1';
  siteLanguage = 'english';
  languageList = [
    { code: 'english', label: 'English' },
    { code: 'espaniol', label: 'Español' },
  ];

  constructor(private portfolioService: PortfolioService) {}

  changeLang(localeCode: string) {
    this.portfolioService.changeLang(localeCode);
  }

  scrollTo(section: string) {
    document.querySelector('#' + section)!.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

my template

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let language of languageList">
             

                <li role="menuitem">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeLang(language.code)">
                    {{ language.label }}
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ng-container>
```

and my component that load the data

```
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private datosPortfolio: PortfolioService) {}
  miPortfolio: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datosPortfolio.obtenerDatos().subscribe((data) => {
      this.miPortfolio = data;
    });
  }
}
```

i tried to make a portfolio where i could change the language with a service that picked up when a changed happened in the header. the changed get picked up but the language is not changed in other components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap your data source observable with observable that changes when language changes. for that, the best is to use the `BehaviorSubject`.
take a look at this:

```
export class PortfolioService {
  language = new BehaviorSubject<string>('espaniol');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  obtenerDatos(): Observable<any> {
    return this.language.asObservable().pipe(
      switchMap(lang => this.http.get(`./assets/i18n/${lang}.json`))
     )
  }

 changeLang(value: string) {
   // update the value of this BehaviorSubject, and all 
   // subscribers notify about it 
   this.language.next(value);
 }
}
```

this way every time language changed, new source emit in this.language BehaviorSubject and subscribe function fires again because of the new value, and them switch to other observable that makes the HTTP request with the language as a parameter that goes into the URL of the request.

hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you very much, you made it so simple yet is difficult to understand everything you just  did. for example i cant understand how we can access the values of a variable when is an observable (beheavioursubject or subject). i dont understand what the pipe and the switchmap do also

Comment: For BehaviourSubject you can get the value using `getValue` method. About pipe and pipe operators such as switchMap - you should read about it - it's important concept that needs time for understanding